# Inject into react internals from javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am building a chrome extension content script that needs to modify the behaviour of a production react application that is live on a website.

I want to be able to run code into the app that changes some function behaviour, perhaps a react hook.

Is there a way to access the react instance from a script? Or in some other way change the implementation of functions that are live on a react app?